# Regular Expression for dialing prefix eg +44 etc

Tags: c#, regex

I realise making a regex for all internation numbers is futile. So as a compromise I need a regex that will check that a string starts with the international dialing code eg:

(+44) or (+33) etc.

I dont understand how to write regex's yet, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

P.s. It's for use in a c#.net project.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this

```
var regex=new Regex(@"^\(\+\d{1,4}\)");
```

I'm using the @ bit before the string so you don't need to double escape \

This does

`^` Match Start of string

`\(` Match (

`\+` Match +

`\d{1,4}` Match 1-4 digits

`\)` Match bracket

Also as you are using c# you may wish to consider using [Expresso](http://www.ultrapico.com/Expresso.htm) as this helps you build and test regular expressions targeted at the .Net Regular expression library and can even generate c# code for you to use them.

Comment: The U.S. has country code 1, and Russia has 7. There are also 3- and 4-digit country codes.

Comment: The last bracket has currently no backslash.

Comment: Doh! I am all thumbs today. Now fixed

Comment: Interesting strategy to become the first poster.

Comment: (was offtopic - should have added a ;-) - first to create a post and then let help the others to correct)

Comment: @Bob Vale Thanks!! It's really appreciated.

Comment: @Bob Vale Does does this also take account of the fact that the prefix will be followed by a number. I don't need to check the subsequent numbers, I just need to check that the start of a number is always(+44) followed by the number eg: (+44)xxxxxxxx

Comment: @Phill Healey: No I'm only matching the prefix you need to add `\d+$` on the end which matches atleast on digit following or you could use `\d{1,5}$` to match between 1 and 5 digits (change the values of 1 and 5 as you need)

Comment: The answer would also match `(+44)FISH!` so you may want to look at my previous comment

Comment: @Bob Vale - Yes but I can handle that sepertately. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is a complex matter, since the phone number needs not to be formatted, so it may have a digit right after the country code. Since these codes can have a varying length, you will need a list of country codes to check for. America and Russia have 1 and 7 respectively, most European countries and larger other countries have a two digit code, but there are also codes with 3 digits (not more, I believe). So you'll need a list of 1 and 2 digit codes at least, and can assume 3 digits if your phone number does not start with any code in that list.

I'd get this clear before you even start thinking whether to build this using regex or not. It may be easier in a simple piece of code.